# iOS UIWebView intercept link click

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, hyperlink

Is it possible intercept when a user clicks a link in a UIWebView and retrieve the link?

I wish to block the UIWebView from going to the clicked link and do something else.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yes, look at the [UIWebViewDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView%3ashouldStartLoadWithRequest%3anavigationType%3a), specifically `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`

The `NSURLRequest` will let you know where the link they clicked is going to direct them.

You would simply return `NO` on this method if you want to prevent the request from loading.

Comment: I need to retrieve the content to memory only, examine it and if it's ok then display it in UIWebView.  Is that possible?

Comment: You might want to use an `NSURLConnection` to download the content do you check, and then load that from disk into a webview if I understand correctly.