# Native IOS App recieve data from webbrowser javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I have a app with storyboard and navigationViewController. On one page, i have a webView object, which contains a webshop. In this view i had to hide the top bar, because i want to use this place for my own html5-bar.

Now my question. Is it possible to trigger the (hidden) backbutton via javascript from webView?

### E D I T

I tried this code from the solution-link

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    [self.browser loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebshop.com/mobile/"]]];
}


-(void) webView:(UIWebView *)browser shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
    if ( [[[inRequest URL] scheme] isEqualToString:@"callback"] ) {

        NSLog(@"Catched Succesfull");
    }
    NSLog(@"NOT Catched");
}
```

But it catches not the event. There is no logging. Did i misunderstood something?

Comment: Are you trying to go back to the previous view? Or have the webview go back to the previous page?

Comment: Sorry. I have a backButton (in HTML), which should close the IOS webview. Just like clicking the backbutton in IOS. As said before. My header for the View, which contains the webview is hidden.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873899/javascript-in-uiwebview-callback-to-c-objective-c)

Comment: Did you set your webview's delegate to the class you implemented this method in?

Comment: i have updateded my code. And in my ".h" i have IbOutlet "@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *browser;"

Comment: `UIWebView` has a delegate property and you must set it to the class that implements the delegate methods.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in `history.back()` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp

Answer (score 1):

A popular way (the only way I know) to call back to the `UIWebView` is to use a custom URI that you intercept. You can see this SO post [iOS UIWebView intercept link click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437305/ios-uiwebview-intercept-link-click)

Format the `href` to something like `myapp://closeWebView`, then in the delegate method you can listen for that URI, once detected call your native ObjC code to close the `UIWebView`